# Automatic scroll on href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add some improvements to a site that I haven't developed, and I currently have a navigation panel on the page. The HTML for this is below

```
<div id="calendar-nav-container">
<span class="calendar-nav" style="float: left"><a href="/Calendar?startDate=15%2F06%2F2015&amp;calendarType=Courses"> &lt;&lt;&lt; </a></span>
<span class="calendar-nav" style="float: left"><a href="/Calendar?startDate=29%2F06%2F2015&amp;calendarType=Courses"> &lt; </a></span>
<span class="calendar-nav" style="float: right"><a href="/Calendar?startDate=27%2F07%2F2015&amp;calendarType=Courses"> &gt;&gt;&gt; </a></span>
<span class="calendar-nav" style="float: right"><a href="/Calendar?startDate=13%2F07%2F2015&amp;calendarType=Courses"> &gt; </a></span>
<form action="/Calendar" id="calendarForm" method="get">        <label for="CalendarType">
        <select name="calendarType">
            <option value="Courses" selected="selected">By Course</option>
            <option value="Venues">By Venue</option>
            <option value="Trainers">By Trainer</option>
        </select></label>
    <label for="LocationId"><select id="locationId" name="locationId">
<option value="">All Locations</option>
<option value="1">Brighton</option>
<option value="2">London</option>
<option value="3">Leeds</option>
<option value="4">New York</option>
<option value="5">Frankfurt</option>
<option value="6">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="7">Toronto</option>
<option value="8">Dublin</option>
<option value="9">Cape Town</option>
<option value="10">Glasgow</option>
<option value="11">Newcastle</option>
<option value="16">Singapore</option>
<option value="17">Birmingham</option>
</select></label>
    <label for="DaysToShow"><select id="daysToShow" name="daysToShow">    
<option value="5">1 week</option>
<option value="19">3 weeks</option>
</select></label>
    <label for="StartDate"><input id="startDate" name="startDate" type="text" value="06/07/2015" class="hasDatepicker"></label>
    <label for="IncludePond" style="color: white"><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Boolean field is required." id="includePond" name="includePond" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="includePond" type="hidden" value="false">Include Pond Courses </label> 
</form></div>
```

I want to maintain page scrolling when these options or links are clicked or chosen. I have limited HTML knowledge.

Comment: what does it mean _I want to maintain page scrolling_

Comment: so the navigation box is `position:absolute` so it does not scroll with the page. when a value in it get changed, as described in the above code, I want the new page scrolled down by the same amount as before the option was chosen.